# typeof returns object but getting error: "undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently working with the following object called `data`:

```
Object {
   "getOrder": Array [
      Object {
         "__typename": "Order",
         "id": 1,
         "items": Array [
            Object {
               "__typename": "Item",
               "id": 1,
            },
            Object {
            "__typename": "Item",
            "id": 2,
         },
      ],
   },
 ],
}
```

When I try to access `data.getOrder`, I get the the error `undefined is not an object`. When I `console.log(typeof data.getOrder)` it outputs object. When I just print `data.getOrder`, it correctly prints the array above.

Why is it that when I try to do `data.getOrder[0]` I get the above error? To me it seems that it is an object based on what I am printing and checking.

Comment: 'When I try to access data.getOrder, I get the the error' & 'When I just print data.getOrder, it correctly prints the array' are contradictory. when u print also u access

Comment: What do you mean "just print"? Are you getting a runtime error when you call `console.log`? Or are you referring to chrome dev tools? Can you also provide a live example (codepen/jsfiddle) of this failing?

Comment: @SudhakarRS when I say access, I mean to say I can not get any data from `data.getOrder`. When I try `const order = data.getOrder[0]` I get the above error. When I run `console.log(data.getOrder)`, it prints the array. Sorry it used wrong terminology

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
console.log(typeof data.getOrder[0]);
```

And using it

```
data.getOrder[0].id
```

Because `getOrder` is an `Array`.

If you using `typeof` to get data type of an array, result `object`

To check an Array

```
function isArray(a){
    return (
        typeof(a) === Object.name.toLowerCase() && (
            a instanceof Array || 
            Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: When I run that console.log, I get the following error: `TyperError: undefined is not an object`

Comment: @user081608 , I think there's a typo somewhere in your code. You should add you code here

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "getOrder": [{
    "__typename": "Order",
    "id": 1,
    "items": [{
        "__typename": "Item",
        "id": 1,
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Item",
        "id": 2,
      }
    ]
  }]
}

console.log(data.getOrder[0].__typename);
console.log(data.getOrder[0].items[0].__typename);
console.log(data.getOrder[0].items[1].id);
```